# AutoHotKey - Looping through file dosen't stop after file ends, Send not sending variable

Tags: autohotkey

So this is my very first AHK program and I am not at all familiar with the language. I am familiar with C# though. I have the following `program that loops trough a file and splits a username and password split by a pipe (|) symbol. Right now when I run the program, it does not stop looping after the end of the file.

In addition, I try to access the username and password separated by the pipe symbol using the StrSplit function. so far, when I run the program, the username is only sometimes `entered`correctly into the browser. The password is not entered into the browser. I am pretty sure `I am using the right mouse coordinates.

Thanks in advance` for the help!

```
#SingleInstance, Force
SetWorkingDir, %A_ScriptDir% ; if an absolute path isn't specified

;; GUI input
;-------------------------------
; ---------------------------------------
Gui, Add, Button, x10 y20 gStart, Start the tool
Gui, Show, w300 h300, Steam Tool    
return

; Labels
; -----------------------
; --------------------------------

Start:    
Loop, read, accounts.txt    ; the file name must be separated by a comma
{
    ; MsgBox %A_LoopReadLine%
    loop, parse, A_LoopReadLine, 
    {                
        IfWinNotExist, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
        { 
            Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Multiloginapp\multiloginapp.exe
            WinWait, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
            Sleep, 20000
        }
        IfWinNotActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15, ,WinActivate, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
        WinWaitActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
        Click 724, 260
        sleep, 1500
        WinWait, Multiloginapp - Mozilla Firefox
        WinActivate, Multiloginapp - Mozilla Firefox
        WinWaitActive, Multiloginapp - Mozilla Firefox
        Click 408, 55
        Sleep 5000
        Send, ^a
        Send, {Backspace}
        SendInput, store.steampowered.com/account    ; SendInput is faster in sending text
        Send, {enter}
        Sleep, 5000
        ; Use:
        ; SendInput, %A_LoopField%
        ; if you want to send the current substring (field) from the line
        s:=StrSplit(A_LoopReadLine, "|")
        Click, 149, 355
        urnme := s[0]
        Send, %usrnme%
        Click, 172 455
        pwd := s[1]
        Send, %pwd% 
        Click, 87 507


    }
}
return
```

Comment: Looks to me like you are using Loop, Parse wrong. I'd try loop, parse, A_LoopReadLine, CSV since you mention your file is Comma Separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
#SingleInstance, Force
SetWorkingDir, %A_ScriptDir% ; if an absolute path isn't specified

;; GUI input
;-------------------------------
; ---------------------------------------
Gui, Add, Button, x10 y20 gStart, Start the tool
Gui, Show, w300 h300, Steam Tool    
return

; Labels
; -----------------------
; --------------------------------

Start:
IfWinNotExist, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
{ 
     Run, C:\Program Files (x86)\Multiloginapp\multiloginapp.exe
     WinWait, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
     Sleep, 20000
}
IfWinNotActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15, ,WinActivate, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
WinWaitActive, Multiloginapp - 01.3.15
Click 724, 260
sleep, 1500
WinWait, Multiloginapp - Mozilla Firefox
WinActivate, Multiloginapp - Mozilla Firefox
WinWaitActive, Multiloginapp - Mozilla Firefox
Click 408, 55
Sleep 5000
Send, ^a
Send, {Backspace}
SendInput, store.steampowered.com/account    ; SendInput is faster in sending text
Sleep, 300
Send, {enter}
Sleep, 5000

; If the title of the window changes after this, you should use:
; WinWait, new title
; WinActivate, new title
; WinWaitActive, new title

Click, 149, 355

; ... continue using one of the next options    
; ...

return
```

First option - Send username and password directly (without reading a file):

```
SendInput, username
Sleep, 300
Click, 172, 455 ; or Send, {Tab} if it activates the password field
Sleep, 300
SendInput, password
Click, 87, 507 ; or Send, {enter} if it activates the log-in field
```

Second option - If you have to read username and password from a file:

```
FileReadLine, OutputVar, accounts.txt, 1 ; If username|password (without spaces) is the first line in this file
usrnme := StrSplit(OutputVar,"|").1
pwd := StrSplit(OutputVar,"|").2
SendInput, %usrnme%
Sleep, 300
Click, 172, 455 ; or Send, {Tab} if it activates the password field
Sleep, 300
SendInput, %pwd%
Sleep, 300
Click, 87, 507 ; or Send, {enter} if it activates the log-in field
```